# How to safely store and use ssh password for use with phpseclib

Tags: ssh, phpseclib

I need to connect to my server through SSH using phpseclib but obviously the password for my server is THE most sensitive in the world to me! How can I use it in the following code in the knowledge it's safe?

```
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.littleninjamedia.co.uk');
if (!$ssh->login('$username', '$password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}
```

I know enough about hashing and passwords etc but I've never had to protect a truly important one! Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this... and this is what I think I shall do.

[Handling passwords in codeigniter](http://www.haughin.com/2008/02/handling-passwords-in-codeigniter/)

Obviously this only helps if you use codeigniter, which I do.

Answer (score 0):

What if you require the password be entered in an HTML POST variable and pass $_POST['password'] to the $ssh object?

Comment: I'm not sure if you mean this as a solution or an indication of a potential problem? What phpseclib will be doing will be automatic when called without any interaction of any kind, simply pulling the password from the database.